# I am getting cmake failed error when executing catkin_make command for Ros packages

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu on a virutal box to run ROS melodic. I have made some package to build custom message.
when i try to catkin_make i get the cmake failed error.

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/hitesh/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hitesh/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/hitesh/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347732/i-am-getting-cmake-failed-error-when-executing-catkin_make-command-for-ros-packages/) by [hitesh khanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/52940/hitesh-khanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-28**:\

> I have attached the screenshot as well

there is no screenshot attached.

This is a good thing, as error messages are text. Text should not be shown in a screenshot, but just copied into your question, verbatim.

Please copy-paste the error message into your question, select the lines of the error and press `ctrl+k` or click the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like Catkin detects Python 3 as the default interpreter. ROS Python packages are installed for the default version of Python which is Python 2 on Ubuntu Bionic (since you tagged `melodic`). Please see #q337135 and #q340510. The answers are clear and comprehensive.

In short, you will either need to make Catkin use the Python 2 interpreter (recommended) or install `catkin_pkg` for the Python 3 interpreter.

---

Originally posted by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) with karma: 241 on 2020-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1